# How do I make two cmd commands on same line

Tags: windows, command-line, script

I was browsing many threads like this but I didnt found any specific that would help, so this is my problem I have this :

```
echo START %USERNAME% > exec3.txt & dir c: /B /S | find ".exe" >> exec3.txt & echo STOP %username% >> exec3.txt
```

And  I need output in this `exec.txt` file that username and .exe path are on same line not above and under.

I am still novice in this so please if you can help me thank you.

Edit: Ok so what I currently get from this code is this:

```
START remak  
C:\05b7ba810261bb83a30acb4b8289\Setup.exe
C:\05b7ba810261bb83a30acb4b8289\SetupUtility.exe
C:\0f669298b95e17eb4420fab939d6058e\Setup.exe
C:\0f669298b95e17eb4420fab939d6058e\SetupUtility.exe
C:\5179a24a27196222747e\Setup.exe
C:\5179a24a27196222747e\SetupUtility.exe
C:\611f293b57db179b197d\Setup.exe
C:\611f293b57db179b197d\SetupUtility.exe
C:\doublecmd\doublecmd.exe

STOP REMAK
```

Remak is username, and I need that REMAK will be on same line as path like this:

```
REMAK C:\05b7ba810261bb83a30acb4b8289\Setup.exe
```

Comment: I'm not too sure what you are asking, could you provide an example of what the text file should look like?

Comment: I think he wants output something like "start username exe file stop username" on one line, possibly with &s between. a better statement of the goal would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
::This is a comment

::Stops the console window from being spammed (and therefore speeds things up a bit)
@echo off

::Create a new file (WARNING: THIS OVERWRITES EXISTING FILES)
type NUL > exec.txt

::Loop through each line outputted by the command 'dir /b /s C:\*.exe'
::The echo command is executed once for each loop iteration
::This can take a very long time, depending on how big your C: partition is
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /s C:\*.exe') do (
    echo START %USERNAME% %%a STOP %USERNAME%>>exec.txt
)
```

Comment: Just my dumb question whats %%a.

Comment: It's part of the `for` command. When run from a batch file, it's `%%a`. When run from the prompt directly, it's `%a`. The letter can be anything. Since there's the `tokens=*`, `%%a` contains the entire line from the command each iteration, including spaces. Normally it delimits, e.g. by spaces, so `C:\Program Files\` might have `%%a = C:\Program` `%%b = Files\`. See `for /?`, http://ss64.com/nt/for.html and specifically http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html.

Comment: Ok its working, solved thank you very much I just deleted one % since I dont run it from batch file :)

Comment: If it worked for you, please [mark this answer as accepted by clicking the arrow to the left](http://superuser.com/faq#howtoask).